# Azure Python WebApp 'Service Unavailable' With Pyodbc

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, pyodbc

I have a Web App in Azure, that runs in Python.
I'm running Python with Flask on Azure and its going everything ok, but then I imported pyodbc to connect my sql server, also on Azure, and after this import i'm having 'service unavailable' when I access my url.

This problem occurs only when I import pyodbc.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi, any progress now?If my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, 'service unavailable' is because of the program internal issue. You could check the log on the KUDU url `https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.

Please refer to my working steps to install `pyodbc` module.

***view.py***

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template
from jaygongflask import app
import pyodbc

@app.route('/database')
def database():
    """Renders the about page."""
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=***.database.windows.net;DATABASE=***;UID=***;PWD=***')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from dbo.Student")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    #for r in row:
     #   print r
    return render_template(
        'database.html',
        title='Database',
        year=datetime.now().year,
        message='Database query result.',
        queryResult = row
    )
```

***web.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="jaygongflask.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Install pyodbc package***

My web app works with python361x64 extension. Please refer to the steps I did as below:

Step 1 : Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.1 x64)

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install pyodbc package or any packages you need via python -m pip install pyodbc

[image]

More deployment details , please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publishing-to-azure).

***Get query result***

Access the url `http://***.azurewebsites.net/database` .

[image]